# Mirth server returns Net::HTTPServerException (403 "Forbidden") on every requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, httparty, mirth

I'm trying to perform an HTTP request to a Mirth Server API through a Rails application, but it always returns Net::HTTPServerException (403 "Forbidden"). I can't understand what is the problem.
If I use the same URL and set `Content-Type: application/xml` in Google's Advanced Rest Client, it works, but from my rails app it returns the above error. The same problems happens if I try to perform a post to authenticate a user in that Mirth API (see code below).

This is the code in my controller:

```
@login = HTTParty.post("https://#{server}:#{port}/api/users/_login",
                         {:body => [{"username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "xxxxxxxxxxx"}],                              
                          :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                        'Accept' => 'application/xml'}
                         })


@response = HTTParty.get("https://#{server}:#{port}/api/server/configurationMap",
                           {:basic_auth => {:username => "xxxxxxxx", :password => "xxxxxxxxxxx"},
                            :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'}
                          })
```

If I make the request using curl via the rails git bash, it also gives the same error.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/xml' -d 'username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxx' 'https://192.168.4.196:8444/api/users/_login'


curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' 'https://192.168.4.196:8444/api/server/configurationMap'
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance!